# Linux dependencies between packages

Tags: linux, dependencies

I have following error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-kernel-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic but it is not going to be  installed
                    Depends: linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to remove this using this commands but no effect. I'm getting the same error.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
```

Thanks for all tips.

Edit:
I tried apt-get -f install but the same problem. Also synaptics can't remove this.

Edit2:

```
$ apt-cache policy
 Package files:
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 release a=now
500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=LP-PPA-xorg-edgers,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=xorg-edgers fresh X crack,c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=LP-PPA-xorg-edgers,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=xorg-edgers fresh X crack,c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=X Updates,c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=X Updates,c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rwky/redis/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=LP-PPA-rwky-redis,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Redis,c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
  500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rwky/redis/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=LP-PPA-rwky-redis,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Redis,c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
  500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg/main i386 Packages
 release o=apt.postgresql.org,a=precise-pgdg,n=precise-pgdg,l=PostgreSQL for Debian/Ubuntu repository,c=main
 origin apt.postgresql.org
  500 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
 release o=apt.postgresql.org,a=precise-pgdg,n=precise-pgdg,l=PostgreSQL for Debian/Ubuntu repository,c=main
 origin apt.postgresql.org
  500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy/partner i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Canonical,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Partner archive,c=partner
 origin archive.canonical.com
  500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy/partner amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Canonical,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Partner archive,c=partner
 origin archive.canonical.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/universe Translation-en
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/restricted Translation-en
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/multiverse Translation-en
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main Translation-en
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-security,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
 origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/universe i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-security,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
 origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/restricted i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-security,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
 origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-security,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=main
 origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-security,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
 origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/universe amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-security,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
 origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-security,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
 origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-security,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=main
 origin security.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe Translation-pl
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe Translation-en
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/restricted Translation-pl
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/restricted Translation-en
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-pl
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/multiverse Translation-en
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main Translation-pl
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main Translation-en
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-updates,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-updates,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-updates,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-updates,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=main
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-updates,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-updates,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-updates,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy-updates,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=main
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe Translation-pl
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe Translation-en
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/restricted Translation-pl
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/restricted Translation-en
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/multiverse Translation-pl
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/multiverse Translation-en
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main Translation-pl
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main Translation-en
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/multiverse i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/restricted i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=main
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/multiverse amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/restricted amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=Ubuntu,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Ubuntu,c=main
 origin archive.ubuntu.com
  700 http://extra.linuxmint.com/ petra/main i386 Packages
 release v=16,o=linuxmint,a=petra,n=petra,l=linuxmint,c=main
 origin extra.linuxmint.com
  700 http://extra.linuxmint.com/ petra/main amd64 Packages
 release v=16,o=linuxmint,a=petra,n=petra,l=linuxmint,c=main
 origin extra.linuxmint.com
  700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ petra/import i386 Packages
 release v=16,o=linuxmint,a=petra,n=petra,l=linuxmint,c=import
 origin packages.linuxmint.com
  700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ petra/upstream i386 Packages
 release v=16,o=linuxmint,a=petra,n=petra,l=linuxmint,c=upstream
 origin packages.linuxmint.com
  700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ petra/main i386 Packages
 release v=16,o=linuxmint,a=petra,n=petra,l=linuxmint,c=main
 origin packages.linuxmint.com
  700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ petra/import amd64 Packages
 release v=16,o=linuxmint,a=petra,n=petra,l=linuxmint,c=import
 origin packages.linuxmint.com
  700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ petra/upstream amd64 Packages
 release v=16,o=linuxmint,a=petra,n=petra,l=linuxmint,c=upstream
 origin packages.linuxmint.com
  700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ petra/main amd64 Packages
 release v=16,o=linuxmint,a=petra,n=petra,l=linuxmint,c=main
 origin packages.linuxmint.com
  500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nviennot/tmate/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=LP-PPA-nviennot-tmate,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=tmate,c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
  500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nviennot/tmate/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=LP-PPA-nviennot-tmate,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=tmate,c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
  500 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/ dist/10gen i386 Packages
 release v=dist,o=10gen,a=10gen,n=dist,l=10gen,c=10gen
 origin downloads-distro.mongodb.org
  500 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/ dist/10gen amd64 Packages
 release v=dist,o=10gen,a=10gen,n=dist,l=10gen,c=10gen
 origin downloads-distro.mongodb.org
  500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu/ saucy/main i386 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=LP-PPA-bumblebee-stable,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Stable Bumblebee releases,c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
  500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
 release v=13.10,o=LP-PPA-bumblebee-stable,a=saucy,n=saucy,l=Stable Bumblebee releases,c=main
 origin ppa.launchpad.net
```

Pinned packages:

```
 $ apt-cache policy linux-kernel-generic linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic
 linux-kernel-generic:
   Installed: 3.11.0-12
   Candidate: 3.11.0-12
   Version table:
  *** 3.11.0-12 0
    700 http://packages.linuxmint.com/ petra/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic:
   Installed: (none)
   Candidate: 3.11.0-12.19
   Version table:
      3.11.0-12.19 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Post the output of `apt-cache policy; apt-cache policy linux-kernel-generic linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic`.

Comment: Why are you mixing ubuntu and linux mint packages at the same priority? that's a bad idea. You have way too much stuff in your sources.list. Strip it down to your basic distribution sources. And are you running mint or ubuntu?

Comment: Ok. I don't think you have a real problem, just take everything unnecessary out of there and try again. Also, if you want someone to read your message, prefix it with @username.

Comment: Edit your question and include the full output of `sudo apt-get check` and `sudo dpkg -C`